# Unable to sort Grid rows using column headings in Ext JS 4

Tags: sorting, extjs, extjs4

I have an existing web app in Ext JS, where I am unable to sort by ascending and descending order. When I click on the column headings, the option is there to sort, but the data doesn't actually get sorted, it appears to just refresh in the same order.

In the console on Chrome, I can see that the following log is written:

```
Request result: true
```

And this appears every time I try to click on the column heading *(such as First Name)*, and it directs me  to an "afterRequest" function.

[image: Column Headers]

### View code:

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        stateId: 'stateGrid',
        defaultSortable: true,
        enableColLock: true,
        enableCtxMenu: false,
        columns: [{
            text: 'Account No',
            width: 90,
            dataIndex: 'accountNum',
            sortable: true
        }, 

        // More column definitions here...

        }]
      }],

title: 'Accounts',
        height: 700,
        width: 1300,
        store: Ext.getStore('accounts.AccountsListStore'),
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        viewConfig: {
            stripeRows: true
        }
    });
```

Included in the properties is a **"sortable: true"** for each column, and also a **"defaultSortable: true"** for the entire grid.

As for the controller, there isn't much code here, except a function to call the server which requests the relevant account data in **JSON** format and is supposed to load it to a store. As you can see in the screenshot above, it appears to be loading in the correct data.

I have only been using Ext JS 4.0.7 for 2 days, and having had no previous Javascript knowledge,a point in the right direction would be really useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now managed to sort the issue. The issue was in my Account store. 
The following code was preventing the sorting from working correctly.

```
buffered: true,
pageSize: 200,
remoteSort: true,
purgePageCount: 0
```

As it's not actually calculating anything, and literally just retrieving data from the server, I have turned off the buffering/remote sort.

My code now looks like this, and sorting works perfectly:

```
buffered: false,
remoteSort: false
```

Hope this helps anyone else who has the same issue.